# Unix shell script with query is not generating data for query with where clause but without where clause it is generating data for postgres metadata

Tags: postgresql, shell, unix, scripting

I have used Postgres query in shell script to execute and get some result and load to file.
The query is using where clause in which date column is used for postgres database.
Without where clause it is generaing data but with where clause in query it is not generating data.Below is the sample query for reference.

```
psql -h host -p port -U username -w -d databasename -Atc 
"with A as(  select max(col1) as max_inst_id,col2,col3,col4 from 
sch_task_Inst where col5 > timestamp '2018-05-05 02:00:00 - interval 
'1 hours'  group by col1,col2,col3,col4  ) 
select b.col1 as task_nm,A.col1 as run_status,A.col2 as run_log from 
A join sch_task b on A.col1 = b.col1  where A.col2 = 'FAI' ;" >> 
/app/ditechstyle/diserver/app/source/Sch_test.dat
```

Can some one tell me what is the problem with the query where clause?

Comment: Looks OK. Maybe there just are no data that satisfy the condition? If you add some sample data to the question, that might help to clarify the problem.

Comment: What has it got to do with shell script? If the query with `where` clause is wrong or there's no data, obviously it won't work. Check first if the query runs fine from psql prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are missing a single apostrophe after your timestamp. You should have `timestamp '2018-05-05 02:00:00' - interval '1 hours'`, but what you actually have is `timestamp '2018-05-05 02:00:00 - interval '1 hours'`. Note the apostrophe after the `02:00:00`. See examples at [this page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-datetime.html) on PostgreSQL dates and timestamps.

Comment: My bad i sent incorrect format but actually gave it properly as timestamp '2018-05-05 02:00:00' - interval '1 hours' in the query,still i see the same issue.

Comment: Data is coming into filename as Sch_max_failurejob.dat? but not coming to actual file Sch_max_failurejob.dat.

Comment: Try setting the interval to `'1 hour'` instead of `'1 hours'`. Does that work?